# How to share content from table view on Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9, facebook-share

I need help, I am trying to share content on Facebook from TableView which is being retrieved through API. Here is the code

```
if  SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
{
    let fbShare = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    fbShare?.add(NSURL(string: APILinks.serverBaseAddress.initialUrl)! as URL )
    self.present(fbShare!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am getting this error

> isAvailableForServiceType: for com.apple.social.facebook returning NO

Here is the layout design
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE1mp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sharing has been deprecated in iOS 11 cannot be expected to work (as has Twitter, for what it's worth).

If you wish to allow users to share content in iOS, you will need to either use Facebook's own SDK for that purpose or use the `UIActivityViewController` API to present a share sheet.

[Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

[UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller)